# Can I control a foreign key value through MySQL?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony

As I've written in the tittle, I have a dubt about foreign keys on MySQL. The point is I have a class `Persona` on Doctrine and another one called `Incidencia`.

```
    class Persona implements UserInterface, \Serializable
    {
        private $dni;
        private $nombre;
        private $apellidos;
        private $telefono;
        private $direccion;
        private $correo;
        private $codigoPostal;
        private $idPuesto;
        private $idGrupo;
        private $username;
        private $password;

        /**
         * @var boolean
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="es_tecnico", type="boolean", nullable=false)
         */
        private $esTecnico;
    ...
    }

    Class Incidencia {
        private $id;
        private $idTecnico;
        private $idGrupo;
        ...
    }

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `incidencia`;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `incidencia` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `id_persona_tecnico` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_prioridad` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_tipo_incidencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_persona_peticionaria` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_persona_afectada` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_estado_incidencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_grupo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_ambito_afeccion` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `asunto` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `descripcion` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `fecha_apertura` datetime NOT NULL,
      `fecha_cierre` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `tramitandose` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `id_persona_peticionaria` (`id_persona_peticionaria`),
      KEY `id_persona_afectada` (`id_persona_afectada`),
      KEY `id_prioridad` (`id_prioridad`),
      KEY `id_estado_incidencia` (`id_estado_incidencia`),
      KEY `id_tipo_incidencia` (`id_tipo_incidencia`),
      KEY `id_ambito_afeccion` (`id_ambito_afeccion`),
      KEY `id_grupo` (`id_grupo`),
      KEY `id_persona_tecnico` (`id_persona_tecnico`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `incidencia`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C23BDDE75` FOREIGN KEY (`id_prioridad`) REFERENCES `prioridad` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C628BDAE3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_grupo`) REFERENCES `grupo` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C829BBDC6` FOREIGN KEY (`id_persona_afectada`) REFERENCES `persona` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C8A99A9BD` FOREIGN KEY (`id_persona_peticionaria`) REFERENCES `persona` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C8F4984FA` FOREIGN KEY (`id_estado_incidencia`) REFERENCES `estado_incidencia` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728CB2B1B14A` FOREIGN KEY (`id_ambito_afeccion`) REFERENCES `ambito_afeccion` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728CBF1EB32C` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo_incidencia`) REFERENCES `tipo_incidencia` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728CE3611082` FOREIGN KEY (`id_persona_tecnico`) REFERENCES `persona` (`id`);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `persona`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `persona` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_puesto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_grupo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_lugar_trabajo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_localidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_prioridad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dni` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `es_tecnico` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dni` (`dni`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_51E5B69BF85E0677` (`username`),
  KEY `id_localidad` (`id_localidad`),
  KEY `id_lugar_trabajo` (`id_lugar_trabajo`),
  KEY `id_puesto` (`id_puesto`),
  KEY `id_grupo` (`id_grupo`),
  KEY `nombre` (`nombre`),
  KEY `prioridad` (`id_prioridad`),
  KEY `apellidos` (`apellidos`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `incidencia`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C23BDDE75` FOREIGN KEY (`id_prioridad`) REFERENCES `prioridad` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C628BDAE3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_grupo`) REFERENCES `grupo` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C829BBDC6` FOREIGN KEY (`id_persona_afectada`) REFERENCES `persona` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C8A99A9BD` FOREIGN KEY (`id_persona_peticionaria`) REFERENCES `persona` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728C8F4984FA` FOREIGN KEY (`id_estado_incidencia`) REFERENCES `estado_incidencia` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728CB2B1B14A` FOREIGN KEY (`id_ambito_afeccion`) REFERENCES `ambito_afeccion` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728CBF1EB32C` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo_incidencia`) REFERENCES `tipo_incidencia` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_C7C6728CE3611082` FOREIGN KEY (`id_persona_tecnico`) REFERENCES `persona` (`id`);
```

Well, the important one is `Persona.$esTecnico`. If is false, then `$username`, `$password`, `$idPuesto` and `$idGrupo` must be `NULL`. The point is that I have a foreign key attribute, `Incidencia.$idTecnico` in class `Incidencia` to `Persona` and, in my application, they only can connect if the attribute `Persona.$esTecnico` is true, so I need to control that. My doubt is if I can control that behaviour directly in MySQL (with phpmyadmin) or I need to control it with some code in my application.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please include more details here, what table, what result don't mix everything in one.. just make it one by one.. thanks.. if you need a query then we have to stay focus on query first and the other one after.

Comment: @reds I've edited my post. Thank you so much for your recommendation!!! =)

Comment: can you show more details from table? Your sample is just a class

Comment: @reds Here are the tables, thanks!

Comment: it seems like you are working with a database with incident and person record.. just a guess hehe

Comment: i need to create a sample record to this.. just wait.

Comment: what do you mean by this? they only can connect if the attribute Persona.$esTecnico is true.. it mean the user can login or not?

Comment: i almost done with my provided query need to clear that part.

Comment: yep, cause in that table I store "technician" and "user" together because both are people, so I store them in the table "Persona". My application is for manage problems (it is my final graduation project). Only technician can access to my app and manage the users (rows where $isTecnico is false).

Comment: Check the query below if that suit to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check that provided Query:

```
select
person.id_persona_tecnico,
 case when person.es_tecnico = 0 then NULL else person.id_puesto end as id_puesto,
 case when person.es_tecnico = 0 then NULL else person.id_grupo end as id_grupo,
person.id_lugar_trabajo,
person.id_localidad,
person.id_prioridad,
person.dni,
person.nombre,
person.apellidos,
person.telefono,
person.direccion,
person.correo,
person.codigo_postal,
person.es_tecnico,
case when person.es_tecnico = 0 then NULL else person.username end as username,
case when person.es_tecnico = 0 then NULL else person.password end as password
 from


(select
id_persona_tecnico,
id_puesto,
id_grupo,
id_lugar_trabajo,
id_localidad,
id_prioridad,
dni,
nombre,
apellidos,
telefono,
direccion,
correo,
codigo_postal,
es_tecnico,
username,
password
 from persona)as  person



left join



(select
id_persona_tecnico,
id_prioridad,
id_tipo_incidencia,
id_persona_peticionaria,
id_persona_afectada,
id_estado_incidencia,
id_grupo,
id_ambito_afeccion,
asunto,
descripcion,
fecha_apertura,
fecha_cierre,
tramitandose
 from incidencia) as inci

on person.id_persona_tecnico = inci.id_persona_tecnico
```

Comment: Nice, so it need to be controled with SQL query, I can't restrict the behaviour on MySQL itself. Thanks!

Comment: is this what you need?